# is it possible to manipulate a temporary table with triggers?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I created a temporary table and I want to manipulate the data of this table with a trigger, doing update, insert, delete in this temporary table is it possible? Mariadb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to manipulate a temporary table with triggers?

No, it isn't.

You cannot associate a trigger with a TEMPORARY table or a view.

[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html)

Comment: Thank you very much